# awk does not print tabular format output values

Tags: awk

```
awk  BEGIN{print "result1 result2  result3"} 'BEGIN{RS=","}{$1=$1}1' input.txt

result1 result2  result3
abc1    def1     ghi1 lmn1 opq1 rst1 abc2    def2     ghi2 lmn2 opq2 rst2
```

above awk prints all values in single row and need to print the output in different row.  abc1  def1  ghi1 lmn1 opq1 rst1 in one row and abc2  def2  ghi2 lmn2 opq2 rst2 in another row.  Number of words are not fixed per line (may be 3 words or more than 3 words)

input.txt:

```
abc1
def1
ghi1 lmn1 opq1 rst1

abc2
def2
ghi2 lmn2 opq2 rst2
```

Expected Output:

```
result1 result2  result3
abc1    def1     ghi1 lmn1 opq1 rst1
abc2    def2     ghi2 lmn2 opq2 rst2
```

Comment: you set the record separator to comma.  There are no commas in the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed Input_file so changing code here too.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  print "result1","result2","result3"}
NF{
  count++;val=val?val OFS $0:$0}
NF && count==3{
  print val;
  val=""}
END{
  if(val){
    print val}
}' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
result1 result2 result3
abc1    def1    ghi1 lmn1 opq1 rst1
abc2    def2    ghi2 lmn2 opq2 rst2
```

---

Following may also help you here.

```
echo "result1 result2  result3";xargs -n 3 < Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: It prints 3 words per line and number of words are not fixed and should split based on /t

Comment: @spiderman, ok seems your sample is different now, try to put sample(s) in single time itself while posting. Try my EDIT code now and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: It works.  Where to add %s for aligning values with respective columns with header values ( result1  result2  result3) ?

Comment: @spiderman, I have added `OFS="\t"` in code it should be TAB delimited only. for using `%s` then we should use `printf`.

Comment: OFS="\t" does not help.  May be printf

Comment: }' OFS="\t"  Input_file  | column -t  .. removes second row and shows 'column: line too long'

Comment: @spiderman, sorry but I am really not sure why you want printf in it? Could you please do let me know `OFS` is working fine for me.

Comment: It works fine for smaller string value (input like 'abc'  or 'def'), but aligning values with respective bigger column values(like 'abcdfgfddsfdsfdsfdsfsfsdfsdfdsfdsf'   'fsdfdsf'   'dsfdsf sdfds dsfds fdsfdsf sfdsfdsfsfd')   with header (result1  result2  result3) gives formatting/alignment issue

Answer (score 1):

if your records are separated by one of more empty lines you can do this instead

```
$ awk -v RS= 'BEGIN {print "result1","result2","result3"} 
                    {$1=$1}1' file | column -t

result1  result2  result3
abc1     def1     ghi1
abc2     def2     ghi2
```

Comment: Some explanation would have been great

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="" }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "result%d%s", i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
{
    $1 = $1
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
result1  result2  result3
abc1     def1     ghi1
abc2     def2     ghi2
```

Comment: awk -f tst.awk file | column -t  --->  prints everything in single line

Comment: Not given the sample input you posted it doesn't. Look at the answer I posted to see what it outputs. You either have different input than you told us or you aren't running the script I posted. Without seeing both I can't help you debug it, sorry.